# What's the origin of the idiom "Глаз на жопу натянуть"?

Tags: этимология, идиомы

I'm curious as to the etymology of the idiom "глаз на жопу натянуть", which literally means "to pull an eye onto someone's ass". Surfing the net, I found that it was used in the movie, Shirli-Myrli [Ширли-мырли], but I'm more interested in the actual meaning of this idiom.

Comment: http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=92606

Comment: I'm not aware of any usage of this particular phrase before this movie. As far as I know not was not only popularized by this movie, it just came from this movie. This is pretty much like "not in Kansas anymore", actually a lot of idiom came into existence because of movies.

Comment: I definitely knew this idiom before that movie as the first part of idiom `глаз на жопу натяну и моргать заставлю`.

Comment: Выражение "глаз на жопу натягивать" знаю с 1960-х годов.

Comment: @Dmitry before 1971? The problem with that  the original meaning was  to confuse someone, perform a con. Not some physical violence as movie's version implied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This phrase isn't an idiom, but an example of argot (slang belonging to certain social groups (outlaws, youngsters, etc.) and can be found in several dictionaries of Russian argot. Here's one of them:
Большой словарь русских поговорок → Глаз на ж... (на задницу) натянуть

Глаз на ж... (на задницу) натянуть кому. Вульг.-прост.  Vulgar. **Сильно избить, наказать кого-л.  To punish, beat somebody (a threat)**. СПП 2001, 24; Вахитов 2003, 109; Подюков 1989, 128; Мокиенко, Никитина 2003, 103. Since most of the words originate from outlaws, I doubt that we can find any further information.

Comment: we need to look in correctional camps

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка go ahead and good luck.

Comment: and that meaning is pulled from movie. The original meaning it usually had is same as hanging noodles on ears :P

Answer (score 0):

This phrase certainly existed long before Shirli-Myrli was published in 1995. The meaning is similar to *beat the shit out of somebody* in English.

> *А потому что твой дядька и все ваши трудящиеся ― засранцы! ― А вы на бузине негров вешаете! ― А я тебе за такие слова **глаз на задницу натяну**! ― А я из твоего носа хобот сделаю! Но в это время хлынул такой свирепый ливень, что два совершенно замечательных человека побежали в разные стороны. Вечером этого же дня, упаковав чемоданы, они покинули международный дом отдыха «Дружба».* [Аркадий Арканов. В огороде — бузина, в Киеве — дядька. 1989]

> *Стаська: Смотри, Лаундя, Костя Кошенок тебе твой **глаз на твою задницу натянет**...* [Фридрих Горенштейн. Три пьесы. Бердичев. 1988](http://belousenko.imwerden.de/books/Gorenstein/gorenstein_3_plays_1988.pdf)

> *Жуков сволочь, дурак, сукин сын. Я буду тебе морду побивать. **Глаз на попу натягивать**! — довольно чисто по-русски ответил Камацубара.* [Анатолий Усов.
> Комдив Жуков. Халхин-Гол. 1939 год. (1988)](https://imwerden.de/pdf/kinoscenarii_1988_4__ocr.pdf)

> *«А то шмазь сделаем, **глаз на ж… натянем**», ― угодливо добавил кто-то.* [Владимир Личутин. Любостай (1987)]

> *— Так верещала, — говорил Вадька, — весь барак сбежался. Матушке твоей повезло еще — Геркиного бати не было. Он бы ей **глаз на пятку натянул**. У Герки матушка теперь будет — будто в танке горела.* [Анатолий Курчаткин. Фома Галечников по прозванию Галош. 1982]

> *Длинный, все глядевший на Шурика, вдруг рявкнул:
>
> — А ну подь быстро! **Глаз на пятку натяну**!
>
> Ричард пел, будто не слышал.
>
> Подряд, без перерыва, спел он три жутковатые песни, с кровью, с тюремной тоской по любви. Он учел, что парни выпили, и дал чуть больше надрыва.*
> [Леонид Аронович Жуховицкий. Легенда о Ричарде Тишкове. 1972]

Also in the old movie [«Факты минувшего дня»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F), 1981, Grigory Gavrilov (played by Abdulov) says:

> ["А Фиолетовой я **глаз на корпус натяну**, это точно!"](https://youtu.be/1Vo4_C58QsE?t=2384)

Obviously this is a censored version of the same phrase. Note that this phrase was added to the script, it was not present in the [novel](https://coollib.com/b/296031/read) on which the movie is based.

And another example from [The grey wolves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gray_Wolves) movie, 1993, [said by Nikita Khrushchev character](https://youtu.be/JMukYUgHVic?t=5685):

> ― Ну ничего, я их в бараний рог согну! Я им **глаза на жопу натяну**! Они навлекут на свою жопу приключений. У меня преданный экипаж. Сяду в Киеве, мы им с Кошевым такую кузькину мать покажем, что будут только лететь, пердеть и радоваться!

Answer (score -2):

This phrase is just a threat mostly joking. It's something like the other one from the Soviet movie "Gentlemen of Fortune" - Пасть порву, моргалы выколю!
Both jokes come from outlaws, that is true. But now they are sort of folklore. Their origins are since post-war time.
This link may be interesting, too.
https://otvet.mail.ru/question/20916651
Откуда пошло - глаз на жопу натяну ?
Alexandr Kutas
Фраза означает надругательство. В среде заключенных опущенному насильственно набивали татуировку на ягодицы в виде глаз.